# Mac version of _find?

Tags: c++, macos, winapi, xcode5

I'm porting some C++ code from circa 2000 Windows to modern OSX using SDL. Most of the functions found cast about the Win32 libs can be replaced by a single import of std lib.

The exception is the _finddata_t structure, which I found was part of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda16keh.aspx

Can anyone offer a suitable replacement, preferably a drop-in?

Comment: Try Boost::Filesystem, which will be part of C++17

Comment: In UNIX-Like OSs (MacOS X, too) you can use the opendir, readdir, closedir commands to enumerate all files in a directory. Unfortunately you'll get a list of ALL files in a directory (in Windows you would say "\*.\*") because you cannot use wildcards (like "\*.txt") in these functions.

Comment: Martin, I think that is the answer I was looking for - the code in question (on further examination) is simply copying down all the filenames in a particular folder, so opendir seems like it will do what I need. Thanks!